# ViewModel's properties become null when navigating

Tags: xamarin, mvvm, xamarin.forms

I have two Pages, which share the same ViewModel. I did this in order to handle the same data when navigating from Page1 to Page2.
The data that I need when I navigate to Page2 is the text of Page 1 entries, which are binded to the ViewModel. Page1 constructor:

```
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.BindingContext = new ViewModel(this.Navigation);
        }
```

In XAML of Page1:

```
<Entry Text="{Binding Entry1TextFromPage1}"/>
<Entry Text="{Binding Entry2TextFromPage1}"/>
```

In the ViewModel I do:

```
        public ViewModel(INavigation navigation)
        {
            this.Navigation = navigation;
            this.ButtonOnPage1Command = new Command( async () =>
                await this.Navigation.PushAsync(new Page2());
            );
            this.ButtonOnPage2Command = new Command( async () =>
                Use(this.Entry1TextFromPage1); //Here the text is null
                Use(this.Entry2TextFromPage1); //Here the text is null
            );
        }
```

All the binded text entries (from Page1) become null. What am I missing?

Comment: please SHOW the relevant code!

Comment: how are you sharing the VM?   Are you actually passing a ref to the VM when you call Page2?  Or does Page2 create it's own instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Page2 probably don't have its `BindingContext` set to the same ViewModel. Pass your ViewModel as a parameter to your Page2 constructor, so you'd call it like this `PushAsync(new Page2(this))`.

```
public Page2(ViewModel viewModel)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = viewModel;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was doing a stupid error.
Now I don't even need to have a single ViewModel, I have one for each page, because I can pass data between ViewModels via the constructor.